# PHP POST is executed again when running from smartphone CHROME browser

Tags: php, iphone, post

I have a problem with an application request in PHP when running it from a smartphone (iphone) browser.

I basically insert some data into a table with PHP by pressing a submit button and after the insertion, i am redirected "home" to another page. In the php code where i'm processing the $_POST[] array, after i insert the data into the mysql table, I am also setting a $_SESSION[] variable which i then use to display an alert on the "home" page that the specific data is inserted.

Ok, this works fine from a pc browser, but from the phone browser, after I'm redirected "home" after insertion and after the alert is displayed correctly, IF I AM CLOSING THE BROWSER (if I close the chrome app) and then reopen it again, it will reopen the the same page which i left (which is the home page with the alert displayed), but it will also process the form (POST) data again, and it will reinsert the data again... so basically if i am closing the browser and reopen it again, it will insert me a duplicated transaction...

I need a solution for this.. I thought of multiple things, from unsetting $_POST in the same scope where i'm displaying the alert (so basically after i display the alert, i set the $_POST = array()), but this doesn't solve it.
One thing that i thought about and could actually work is to get the state of the "insert" button, I mean to check if it was pressed or not when manipulating the $_POST[] array, in the insertion function.. However, I don't think this can be done via php, but via JS, and i don't really know how to combine both of them (maybe with AJAX?) but i think it's complicating the situation..

Do you know any easier solution?

P.S. I just checked and this happens only on chrome browser from ios.
On Safari for example, this doesn't happen. If i close the browser ad reopen it, it will not insert the same data again.

Thank you!

Comment: Manipulating the $_POST array won't help you at all - the browser is making a _new_ request, sending the same data again, which PHP will parse and provide in $_POST. Any modifications you might have made to $_POST after the data was submitted the _first_ time are completely irrelevant here - those happened in a completely different request-response cycle.

Comment: I figured that is happening already. I need a solution to this.

Comment: If the browser makes the same POST request again, then you have little chance to interfere on the client side. So you will either have to implement some sort of "duplicate check" on the server side; or maybe if you did not make a normal POST request, but sent the data in the first place, the problem should not occur in the first place, I would assume - because the browser repeats the "navigation" request that submitting the actual form caused, but an AJAX request in the background is not navigation. So I would expect that it won't "repeat" any AJAX requests, when you restart the browser.